# Display all Session variables on a .cshtml page

Tags: asp.net, razor

What's the best way to display ALL session variables on a .cshtml page?

Tried using

```
@HttpContext.Current.Session();
```

But that didn't show anything.

Comment: see http://www.xyzws.com/JSPfaq/how-to-display-all-the-session-variables-in-an-html-page/33

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is untested, but should work:

```
@{ var session = HttpContext.Current.Session; }
@foreach (string key in session.Keys) {
    <p>Key: @key - Value: @session[key].ToString()</p>
}
```